# How to create a recurring amount field in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP. I am creating a system which shows customers, subscription package, and balance amount.

I have created user CRUD system and Packages CRUD System. What I want to have is to increase balance amount every 30 days, basically like recurring subscription. What I need is basic guideline.

This works like this -

1. Created a customer
2. Assigned him a Package
3. Balance amount increases every 30 days

(I'm Stuck on 3rd Point)

Comment: You should define cron task that will work every hour/day (depending on how you calculate the subscription time) and check the users whose subscriptions are expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the basic approach would be to:

Do NOT keep track of a "balance", but register the "end date" of the subscription. You can both keep track of the last month paid as the end date of the contract. Actually you can register more dates and make this as complicated as you want.

The "basic guideline" is that in the database you store dates and not balances. This allows you to only make changes as part of a transaction (like paying changing/adding a contract).

Hope this different approach helps you.